# Is there purpose to the sln file in dotnet core using vscode?

Tags: c#, .net

Original unedited question:

Full disclosure, I am a java developer learning dotnet core, on a mac with vscode.  I get what the purpose `.csporj` file is, but I cant seem to find any information on why I need to maintain a `.sln` file.

Ok so maybe I need to make this more explicit.

**I am not using Visual Studio.  I am using vscode.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx contains no references to vscode. Everything I found said that the solution file was for Visual Studio, which to reiterate, I am not using.  I updated the title to make this more apparent.

**So is there a purpose for the solution file in vscode?**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx

Comment: It's a text file. Open it in Notepad.

Comment: So its just a text file to make visual studio happy?  So if I am not using visual studio I can ignore it?

Answer (score 7):

The sln is the equivalent of your eclipse work-space in Java, the csproj is the equivalent of a single java package. The sln is used to tie the source code for multiple assemblies together (for example a executable and its dependencies) in to a single project that can be opened as a whole.

You don't *need* the sln if you are working with a single project (but visual studio will still want to make one when you open a csproj by itself), but if you are working with multiple csproj it is needed to keep the projects together.

Comment: I am not using visual studio at all.  I am using vscode. Is the .sln file still relevant?  This is what I am having a hard time finding information about.

Comment: Yes, vscode can open multiple csproj files at once. The metadata about which projects are together are in the sln file.

Comment: See [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) *"Selecting a *.sln file opens a MSBuild-project. It will load the referenced *.csproj projects and sibling or descendant project.json files but no other project files that are referenced from the solution file."*